# QGIS in Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5?

Tags: qgis

Does QGIS work in Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5? I am planning to buy an outdoor mapping device, but I'm not sure if this OS supports QGIS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No and I think I would be 99% safe in saying that it will never be ported to that platform.

My advice would be a Windows tablet or Android.  Then you have a lot more and better options.